# How can I use RxJs to hold off any requests for an AJAX call until the previous one resolves

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, throttling

I have an observable that represents an action that is triggered by some outside component. For the purpose of this question, let's call it `createBananaAction`.
I have a `bananaService` with a method `create` that performs an AJAX request and returns the created banana as a `Promise`.

So, whenever some data arrives from the `createBananaAction`, we want to call `bananaService.create()`.

The code looks like this: (using [RxJs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS))

```
this.createdBananas = createBananaAction.flatMap(() => bananaService.create());
```

Now, the challenge is to "throttle" the createBananaAction so that it can only request another banana after it received its previous one. Simply put: there can never be two simultaneous calls to `bananaService.create()`.
Note that I do not want to throttle in time, but rather ignore all incoming requests for a new banana while the bananaService is doing its thing.

I did some research and found the seemingly appropriate [`pausable`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/backpressure.md#pausable-observables) operator.

My code now looks like this:

```
const pausableCreateBananaAction = createBananaAction.pausable();

this.createdBananas = pausableCreateBananaAction
    .do(() => pausableCreateBananaAction.pause())
    .flatMap(() => bananaService.create())
    .do(() => pausableCreateBananaAction.resume());
```

This seems to work, but I don't like the fact that I need these `do` statements to manually trigger the `pause` and `resume` statements.

I found out you can pass an observable into `pausable` which should then produce `false` or `true` at appropriate times, but this also requires me to manually push values in a subject. Something like this:

```
const letItGoThrough = new Rx.Subject();

this.createdBananas = createBananaAction
    .pausable(letItGoThrough.startWith(true))
    .do(() => letItGoThrough.onNext(false))
    .flatMap(() => bananaService.create())
    .do(() => letItGoThrough.onNext(true));
```

So now I have an Rx.Subject (subjects are like training wheels for RxJs, it's what you use until you become experienced enough at RxJs that you no longer need them.) and two calls to `do`.

Is there a fully "Reactive" way of doing what I want? Or am I stuck with this construct that looks and feels a bit too imperative for my tastes.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [flatMapFirst](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/flatmapfirst.md) instead of `flatMap`:

```
this.createdBananas = createBananaAction.flatMapFirst(() => bananaService.create());
```

The above assumes your `bananaService.create()` returns a cold observable.  If it returns a hot observable or a `Promise`, then we need to wrap the call with `Observable.defer` to convert it to a cold observable so that `flatMapFirst` can control its firing properly:

```
this.createdBananas = createBananaAction
    .flatMapFirst(() => Rx.Observable.defer(() => bananaService.create()));
```

Comment: No game: `bananaService.create()` can be called multiple times, the only thing flatmapFirst seems to do is only return the first banana, but not stop the bananas from being created.

Comment: Yeah you need to return a cold observable.  If `create` returns a promise or hot observable, then we need to wrap it with `defer`.  I'll update the answer

Comment: As of RxJS5 `flatMapFirst` is called `exhaustMap`.