# Limit number of requests at a time with RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Suppose I have 10 urls, and I wish to make an HTTP request for each one of them.

I could create an observable of the URLs, then `.flatMap()` the requests for each one of them, and then `.subscribe` for the results. But that would make all of the requests at once.

Is there a way to impose a limit to the number of requests to a fixed number, in order not to overload the server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has an answer here : [how-to-limit-the-concurrency-of-flatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111037/how-to-limit-the-concurrency-of-flatmap)
You can also review the answer here [Fire async request in parallel but get result in order using rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486932/fire-async-request-in-parallel-but-get-result-in-order-using-rxjs)

Basically it revolves around using the `merge(withMaxConcurrency)` operator.

Answer (score 14):

### RxJS v6 update

pipe through mergeMap with your parallel limit as 2nd parameter

```
const MAX_PARALLEL_QUERIES = 3;
let allResults = [];
let observables = [] // fill with observables
from(observables)
            .pipe(mergeMap(observable => observable, MAX_PARALLEL_QUERIES))
            .subscribe(
                partialResults => {
                    allResults = allResults.concat(partialResults);
                },
                err => {
                    // handle error
                },
                () => {
                    // get here when all obserable has returned
                    allResults.forEach(result=> {
                        // do what you want
                    });
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 7):

It's 2018, rxjs 5 is here and this is how I solved it

```
urls$
  .mergeMap((url) => request({ url }), null, 10)
  .subscribe()
```

`mergeMap` (aka `flatMap`) already takes the "max concurrency" as its 3rd parameter (see the [docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html))

Btw. I am using universal-rxjs-ajax (the `request`) for node compatibility, but it should work the same with `Observable.ajax`

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, and now found the solution.
reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783559/how-can-i-use-rxjs-to-hold-off-any-requests-for-an-ajax-call-until-the-previous/32783660#32783660)

If you create observable by fromNodeCallback or return Promise, it create a hot observable, and will execute immediately once flatMap and subscribe. So flatMapWithMaxConcurrent or map&merge not work as expected.

```js
var start = Date.now()
var now = ()=>Date.now()-start
var test = Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(function(i, cb){
 console.log(i, 'access', now());
 setTimeout(function(){
  cb(null, i)
 }, 1000);
})

Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3])
 .flatMapWithMaxConcurrent(1, x=>test(x) )
 .subscribe(x=>console.log(x, 'finish', now()))

/* output:
1 access 2
2 access 16
3 access 16
1 finish 1016
2 finish 1016
3 finish 1017
*/
```

```html
<script src="http://www.cdnjs.net/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>
```

You need convert it to cold observable, simply use Rx.Observable.defer.

```js
var start = Date.now()
var now = ()=>Date.now()-start
var test = Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(function(i, cb){
 console.log(i, 'access', now());
 setTimeout(function(){
  cb(null, i)
 }, 1000);
})


Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3])
 .flatMapWithMaxConcurrent(1, x=>Rx.Observable.defer( ()=>test(x)) )
// .map(x=>Rx.Observable.defer( ()=>test(x)) ).merge(1) // this works too
 .subscribe(x=>console.log(x, 'finish', now()))
    
/* output:
1 access 3
1 finish 1004
2 access 1005
2 finish 2005
3 access 2006
3 finish 3006
*/
```

```html
<script src="http://www.cdnjs.net/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note here: in RxJS v5 `fromCallback()` and `fromNodeCallback()` were changed to `bindCallback()` and `bindNodeCallback()` respectively. Link for further reading: [bindNodeCallback](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindNodeCallback)