# RxJs: How can I make synchronous requests?

Tags: javascript, http, asynchronous, rxjs

#### I'm trying to make thousands of http requests at once and my internet connection collapse :)

That's why I was looking to implement a function using *RxJS Observables* that limits simultaneous asynchronous requests to a defined maximum number.

For example, if the max number would be 3, the requests would work like this:

```
r-----R--->
r---R----->
r-------R->
----r---R->
------r--->
--------r->
--------r->
```

Here is a JSBin example where all the request are sent at once with a request mocked function
http://jsbin.com/vemewu/4/edit?js,console

```
function makeTestRequest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });
}

let requests = _.range(0, 100).map(() => makeTestRequest);

var requests$ = Rx.Observable.fromArray(requests);

requests$.subscribe(
  () => console.log('request done'),
  () => console.log('error'),
  () => console.log('completed')
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at `merge(maxConcurrency)` or `flatmapwithmaxconcurrent`overload. You could start by reviewing these two SO questions : [How to limit the concurrency of flatMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111037/how-to-limit-the-concurrency-of-flatmap/26126750#26126750), [Limit number of requests at a time with RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535685/limit-number-of-requests-at-a-time-with-rxjs/34535954#34535954) and then the documentation links :

- for [merge(maxConcurrency)](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/mergeproto.md)
- for [flatmapwithmaxconcurrent](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/flatmapwithmaxconcurrent.md)

Comment: Thanks! I finally achieved it using merge method