# Batching using RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm guessing this should be somewhat easy to achieve but I've having trouble (conceptually, I guess) figuring out how to tackle it.

What I have is an API that returns an array of JSON objects. I need to step through these objects, and, for each object, make another AJAX call. The issue is the system that handles each AJAX call can only handle two active calls at a time (as it's quite a CPU-intensive task that hooks out into a desktop application).

I was wondering how I could achieve this using RxJS (either using version 5 or 4)?

EDIT: In addition, is it possible to have a chain of steps running concurrently. i.e.

`Downloading File: 1
Processing File: 1
Converting File: 1
Uploading File: 1
Downloading File: 2
Processing File: 2
Converting File: 2
Uploading File: 2
Downloading File: 3
Processing File: 3
Converting File: 3
Uploading File: 3`

I've tried doing something like:

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(start())
    .concatMap(arr => Rx.Observable.from(arr))
    .concatMap(x => downloadFile(x))
    .concatMap((entry) => processFile(entry))
    .concatMap((entry) => convertFile(entry))
    .concatMap((entry) => UploadFile(entry))
    .subscribe(
        data => console.log('data', new Date().getTime(), data),
        error => logger.warn('err', error),
        complete => logger.info('complete')
    );
```

However that doesn't seem to work. The downloadFile, for example doesn't wait for processFile, convertFile and uploadFile to all complete, rather, the next one will run again as soon as the previous one completes.

Comment: http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/subscribe.html

Comment: @cport1 - the linked example runs one after the other without waiting for any form of async operation. That's different to what I'm asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are 2 approaches, if you want the sequence of requests exactly like this

```
Downloading File: 1
Processing File: 1
Converting File: 1
Uploading File: 1
Downloading File: 2
Processing File: 2
...
```

You need to resolve all promises inside single concatMap method, like this

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getJSONOfAjaxRequests())
  .flatMap(function(x) { return x;})
  .concatMap(function(item) {
    return downloadFile(item)
      .then(processFile)
      .then(convertFile);
  })
  .subscribe(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

see the working plunkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/iugdlC2PpW3NeNF2yLzS?p=preview
This way, the new ajax call will be sent only when the previous is finished.

Another approach is that allow the files to send requests in parallel but the operations 'downloading,processing,converting,uploading' will be in sequence. For this you can get it working by

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getJSONOfAjaxRequests())
  .flatMap(function(x) { return x;})
  .merge(2)  // in case maximum concurrency required is 2
  .concatMap(function(item) {
    return downloadFile(item);
  })
  .concatMap(function(item) {
    return processFile(item);
  })
  .concatMap(function(item) {
    return convertFile(item)
  })
  .subscribe(function(data) {
    //console.log(data);
  });
```

see plunkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/mkDj6Q7lt72jZKQk8r0p?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, the first one is what I've gone with, although the second would be ideal, if I could limit the amount of parallel operations (i.e. max 2 at a time).

Comment: By the way, this first solution seems only work with rxjs5. The behavior using version 4 runs them all in parallel.

Comment: strange! theoretically the behavior should remain the same on rxjs4 and rxjs5.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `merge` operator with the `maxConcurrency` overload (Rxjs v4), so something like :

```
Rx.Observable.fromArray(aJSONs)
  .map (function (JSONObject) {
    return ajaxRequest(JSONObject) // that would be an observable (or a promise)
  })
  .merge(2)
```

You can have a look to see other examples of use at :

- [Limit number of requests at a time with RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535685/limit-number-of-requests-at-a-time-with-rxjs/34535954#34535954),
- or [How to limit the concurrency of flatMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111037/how-to-limit-the-concurrency-of-flatmap/26126750#26126750)

Official documentation :

- [merge(maxConcurrency)](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/mergeproto.md)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? You could use `from` to break the array into bite sized chunks and process them one by one using `concatMap`.

```
function getArr() {
    return Rx.Observable.of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
}


function processElement(element) {
    return Rx.Observable.of(element)
        .delay(500);
}


getArr()
    .concatMap(arr => {
        return Rx.Observable.from(arr);
    })
    .concatMap(element => {
        return processElement(element);
    })
    .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

Comment: This looks promising, but would it be possible to extend it? i.e. if I wanted to add another step as well?

Comment: I believe you could extend it, yes. You could continue to add concatMaps or whatever other operator you needed. There is a lot of good information here http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I believe this could work, for console log we could use tap. Note editor would through intellisense error since from expects an array, but the code should work.

```
 from(start()).pipe(
    switchMap(files => from(files).pipe(
       switchMap(file => from(downloadFile(file)).pipe(
         map(_ => ({file: file, downloaded: true}))
       )),
       switchMap(attr => from(processFile(attr.file)).pipe(
         map(_ => ({...attr, downloaded: true}))
       )),
       switchMap(attr => from(convertFile(attr.file)).pipe(
         map(_ => ({...attr, converted: true}))
       )),
       switchMap(attr => from(uploadFile(attr.file)).pipe(
         map(_ => ({...attr, uploaded: true}))
       ))
    ))
 ).subscribe(_ => {})
```