# How to use exhaustMap in ReactiveX/rxjs 5 in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular, reactive-programming, rxjs

I was wondering how can I process an array where each value returns a Promise in the same order as they're specified. For example, let's say I want to call multiple Ajax calls in this order:

```
var array = [
    'http://example.org',
    'http://otherexample.org',
    'http://anotherexample.org',
];
```

There's basicaly the same question: [How can I use RxJs to hold off any requests for an AJAX call until the previous one resolves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783559/how-can-i-use-rxjs-to-hold-off-any-requests-for-an-ajax-call-until-the-previous), which suggests using `flatMapFirst`.

Since I'm using Angular2 (`beta-15` at this moment) in TypeScript which uses `rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2` I found out that [`flatMapFirst` has been renamed to `exhaustMap`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.0.0-beta.2/MIGRATION.md#operators-renamed-or-removed).

But this operator isn't listed in [Observable.ts](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.0.0-beta.2/src/Observable.ts), therefore I can't use it. It's not even present in the bundled version of RxJS https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/Rx.js.

So, how am I supposed to use it? Or is there any other way to the what I need? Its [package.json](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.0.0-beta.2/package.json) lists a lot of build scripts, should I force it to use one of them?

Edit: I should mention I'm using [ReactiveX/rxjs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs) library, not [Reactive-Extensions/RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS)

Comment: Based on your problem description, you may actually want to use `concatMap` instead.  It sounds like you want to process all requests without throwing any away.

Comment: You're right `concatMap` did what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Operator `concatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) did the job:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap';

var urls = [
  'https://httpbin.org/get?1',
  'https://httpbin.org/get?2',
  'https://httpbin.org/get?3',
  'https://httpbin.org/get?4',
  'https://httpbin.org/get?5',
];     

Observable.from(this.urls)
  .concatMap(url => http.get(url))
  .subscribe(response => console.log(response.url))
;
```

This prints to console:

```
https://httpbin.org/get?1
https://httpbin.org/get?2
https://httpbin.org/get?3
https://httpbin.org/get?4
https://httpbin.org/get?5
```

Comment: I think "concat" will do the same job, isn't it?

Comment: Not really, `concat` requires you to create the Observable beforehand. With `concatMap` I can make new Observable for each value eas they're emitted.

Comment: @martin, what do you mean by "create the observable beforehand ?" could you provide any code example