# Angular 2 + rxjs - how return stream of objects fetched with several subsequent http requests

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services, rxjs5

I have data classes

```
class Processor {
    frequency: number;
    error: booelan;
}

class Computer {
    name: string;
    processor: Processor[];
}
```

I faetch it from backend using json:

```
{
    "name": "Alfa Beta",
    "processors": [
        {
            "url": "ASD3-455R-FRTT-ASEW"
        },
        {
            "url": "AQW2-DFFFR-367K-MMKE"
        }
    ]
}
```

and single processor

```
{
    "url": "ASD3-455R-FRTT-ASEW",
    "frequency": 2200,
    working: true
}
```

I need to return stream of `Computer` as I'd like to ask for processors status each minute. For single returned instance of `Computer` I need to send 3 http requests with dependencies on each other. Of course I'll use service class for this. The only trouble for me is how to create this stream, ie. `this.http.get(this.mainUrl)`?

I've found [Reactive programming, HTTP and Angular 2](https://jaxenter.com/reactive-programming-http-and-angular-2-124560.html) and chapter *Executing a request with the result of a previous one* but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a job for [`concatMap` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) (btw, I had a very similar question some time ago [How to use exhaustMap in ReactiveX/rxjs 5 in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713531/how-to-use-exhaustmap-in-reactivex-rxjs-5-in-typescript)).

For example running several request in order:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

var urls = [
  'https://httpbin.org/get?1',
  'https://httpbin.org/get?2',
  'https://httpbin.org/get?3',
  'https://httpbin.org/get?4',
  'https://httpbin.org/get?5',
];     

Observable.from(this.urls)
  .concatMap(url => http.get(url))
  .subscribe(response => console.log(response.url))
;
```

This prints to console:

```
https://httpbin.org/get?1
https://httpbin.org/get?2
https://httpbin.org/get?3
https://httpbin.org/get?4
https://httpbin.org/get?5
```

Operator `concatMap()` maps each value (each URL in our case) into an `Observable` and re-emits all its values until it's complete. Then it carries on with the next `Observable` returned from the callable. We know that `http.get()` returns an `Observable` that emits just one value with the `Response` object and then completes.

See plnkr demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/PJ7SpkNgBjZz2h4uvRpK?p=preview (in `app.component.ts`)

You said the request depend on each other (one request is dependent on the result of the previous request?) so maybe a better solution could be the following:

```
http.get('https://httpbin.org/get?1')
  .do(response => console.log('Process response', response.url))

  .concatMap(response => {
    console.log('Previous response', response.url, ' about to run /get?2')
    return http.get('https://httpbin.org/get?2')
  })
  .do(response => console.log('Process response', response.url))

  .concatMap(response => {
    console.log('Previous response', response.url, ' about to run /get?3')
    return http.get('https://httpbin.org/get?3')
  })

  .subscribe(response => console.log('Done', response.url))
;
```

Output in console:

```
Process response https://httpbin.org/get?1
Previous response https://httpbin.org/get?1  about to run /get?2
Process response https://httpbin.org/get?2
Previous response https://httpbin.org/get?2  about to run /get?3
Done https://httpbin.org/get?3
```

Again, we're using `concatMap()` to turn each value into an `Observable` but this time we're using it to only guarantee the correct order and to be able to access the result from the previous `http.get()` call. I also used [`do()` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do) only to separate logic that processes the previous response from logic that creates the next request for better readability (even though this could all go into `concatMap()`).

See plnkr demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/VFv09dTekK8av1Pu3a75?p=preview (in `app.component.ts`)