# Observable Continue calling API and changing parameters based on condition

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I've read the [Rx.js repeat](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/repeat.html) Documentation in an effort to find out how I can continue calling an api based upon the response that I receive from the `API`. I'm calling an `API` that can only send back `2k` records at a time. The API will send back a value for me to send it so that I can continue receiving the records until they return a done value.

So the flow goes as follows:

1. Make a `GET` request a query parameter `reqMode=''`:
2. retrieve response with the last array containing `reqMode` with a `value` or `done`.
3. If I receive a `value` then I need to make the same request but send the `reqMode` parameter with the value.
4. If i receive `done` then I'll stop and return all of the records since the first call.

I get the first set of values when `subscribing normally`, but this would be my attempt after reading the docs, but it doesn't make sense:

```
getRecords(){
    let url = this.url + 'reqMode=';
    return this.http.get(url)
            .doWhile() //What would I do here
}
```

When trying to do `.doWhile` with a Observable that is type `Observable<response>`. I'm looking for any alternative using Observables for what I need to do.

Comment: angular2 ships with rxjs5-beta and based in the documentation you wont be able to use .doWhile... at least not yet: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#operators-renamed-or-removed. Are you looking for alternate solutions? or only for rxjs4?

Comment: I'm fine with an alternative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think `repeat()` is a good operator for this. If I understand you correctly you want to repeat the HTTP request based on the response of the previous request. Operator `repeat()` is good if you wanted to repeat **the same** request multiple times.

I'd use [`concatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) and recursively call itself until the `reqMode` is eqaul to `"done"`:

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/w0DdepslTaKrLSB3aIkA

```
import {Observable, Subject} from 'rxjs';

const result = new Subject();
const closeBuffer = new Subject();
const buffer = result.buffer(closeBuffer.asObservable());

function sendHttpRequest(reqMode) {
  return Observable.of('{"reqMode":' + reqMode + '}')
    .map(response => JSON.parse(response))
    .concatMap(data => {
      console.log('HTTP Response:', data);
      // Add data to the buffer of results
      result.next(data);

      if (data.reqMode == 'done') {
        // Return an empty value wrapped as an Observable so concatMap can work
        // with it and emit onNext when it completes (which is immediately
        // thanks to the `.of()` operator).
        return Observable.of(null);
      } else {
        // Simulate that the next call returns 'done'
        return sendHttpRequest('"done"');

        // Uncomment this for real usage
        //return sendHttpRequest(data.reqMode);
      }
    });
}

// Subscribe to the buffer where I'll receive the value.
buffer.subscribe(val => console.log('Next: ', val));

// Simulate HTTP request with reqMode = 42
sendHttpRequest(42).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('done');
  // Emit values from the buffer.
  closeBuffer.next(null);
  closeBuffer.complete();
});
```

I use [`of()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of) operator to simulate a request and to return a value wrapped as an Observable. I also use `Subject` to hold all responses that are buffered using [`buffer()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-buffer) operator. The I subscribe to the buffer to get the final array of responses (If you wrap this code into a function you'll most likely return the `buffer` where you can subscribe later).

The response is following:

```
HTTP Response: Object {reqMode: 42}
HTTP Response: Object {reqMode: "done"}
Next:  [Object, Object]
```

See similar question: [Angular 2 + rxjs - how return stream of objects fetched with several subsequent http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566268/angular-2-rxjs-how-return-stream-of-objects-fetched-with-several-subsequent/39578646#39578646)

Comment: looks nice! `recursion` has been a weaker point of mine. It's time to step into a new...I'll try this one right now

Comment: @inspired I updated my answer, I didn't realize that you want to stack all responses until `done` which means there might multiple I guess(?) Now it's a little more complicated but I think it's still understandable.

Comment: oh i was trying your method and just pushing each data response to an array in order to gather them all, but I guess that then couples my method to an outside array.

Comment: @inspired Yes, that's also an option. I think you need to have a separate variable where you put your results because the Observable chain works with HTTP responses. More _"functional way"_ would be calling `sendHttpRequest()` along with the accumulated array of results (like `sendHttpRequest('"done"', [obj1, obj2])`) but that would made it quite confusing and it's not even necessary.

Comment: I haven't tried the buffer yet, but concatenating the values to an array works great!

Answer (score 3):

So I made an example on how you can do this by using a wrapping `observer` and using `.repeat()`.

All the logic is in `app.component.ts`

[Checkout this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/flYc1qZN4yXaooRh7gZS?p=preview)

I left comments in the code, but essentially it will make an http request, it will increment a count, and then will make another request with a different query number. It will repeat until it reaches 5.

You will have to modify it so the "repeat condition" represents your logic.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @mrcolombo - How would you add an interval to this so as to only repeat the action every second?

Comment: @DonalRafferty adding `.delay(1000)` before the `.repeat()` will make it execute every second.