# get new ticket then retry first request

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

## Update:

I extend Http class, when I `deleteDocument()` I want handle error then `getTicket()` then retry ma request `deleteDocument()` with new `this.TICKET` :

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {
    public SERVER_URL: string = 'http://10.0.0.183:8080/alfresco/s/'
    public TICKET: string = ''
    
    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }
    

    post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.post(url,body, options));
    }

    intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        return observable.catch(initialError => {
            if (initialError.status === 401) {
                return this.getTicket()
                    .do(res => {
                        // HERE I WANT RETRY MY FIRST REQUEST
                        this.TICKET = res.json().data.ticket
                    })
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(initialError);
            }
        })
    }

    getTicket() {
        return this.post(this.SERVER_URL + 'api/login', JSON.stringify({username: 'admin', password: 'admin'}))
    }


    deleteDocument(idFile: number) {
        return this.post(this.SERVER_URL + 'dms/file/delfile?idfile=' + idFile + '&alf_ticket=' + this.TICKET, {}).map((data: Response) => data.json())
    }
}
```

After receive my new ticket, I want retry my first request with new url. Thanks

Comment: Can you please add the code where you actually to the request? Your retry method will be a new call to the query method so we need to know its signature.

Comment: please apologize, here you are (see update)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's any easier way but I'd use [`concatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) operator and recursively call `deleteDocument()` with the the id returned from the previous call:

This should simulate your situation:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

function deleteDocument(willFail: bool, id) {
  return Observable.of("I'm your response: " + id)
    // process response and eventualy throw error
    .concatMap(val => {
      if (willFail) {
        return Observable.throw({response: val, message: "It's broken"});
      } else {
        return Observable.of(val);
      }
    })
    // recover from the error
    .catch(initialError => {
      return deleteDocument(false, initialError.response.length);
    });
}

deleteDocument(true, 42).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/rUbLgEwtw7lSBueKJ5HN?p=preview

This prints to console:

```
I'm your response: 21
```

I'm simulating the error with `willFail` argument. Operator `concatMap` server here to distinguish between an error and a correct response. I'm also passing along the original `id` and to some processing with just for demonstration purposes.

In your case, you'd append to `intercept()` also all parameters necessary to reconstruct the original HTTP request and instead of `this.getTicket().do()` use:

```
return this.getTicket().concatMap(response => {
    var newBody = {id: response.ticketId};
    return this.post(originalUrl, newBody, ...);
});
```

Operator `do()` is mostly useful to just debug what's going on in your operator chains, it doesn't modify the chain in any way.

I don't know what your code actually does but I hope this makes sense to you.

Maybe a similar question to yours: [Observable Continue calling API and changing parameters based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797698/observable-continue-calling-api-and-changing-parameters-based-on-condition)