# Continue the subscription after error

Tags: javascript, ajax, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I have a code where for each of the ids I am making an ajax request and processing them as results come in. Here is a simple replica of my actual code and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ibrahimislam/nfmnxe62/5/):

```
var ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var ids$ = (id) => {
    return Observable.of(id);
};
var loadIds$ = (id) => {
    if(id == 4) return xhr('/echo/jsoneee/', {id: id});
    return xhr('/echo/json/', {id: id});
};

Observable.from(ids)
.concatMap(id => Observable.forkJoin(ids$(id), loadIds$(id)))
.catch((err, caught) => {
  //get the id for which loadIds failed
  //send the id to subscribe() and continue the subscription
  return Observable.empty();
})
.subscribe(result => console.log(result))
```

But now I need to modify the code so that if an error occurs I will have to get the `id` for which the ajax request failed and then just continue the subscription like nothing happened. I have not been able to do this yet. Help is really appreciated.

Comment: What's this supposed to do `.concatMap(id => Observable.forkJoin(ids$(id), loadIds$(id)))`?

Comment: @martin This is just a mock up to make things simpler. But it can be `forkJoin` or `zip` but the purpose is that `subscribe()` should have the `id` object and the response for that `id` ajax request as a single item together because I am doing other processing inside subscribe and I need both data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can simplify this significantly by emitting correct values right in `Observable.create(...)`:

```
function xhr(url, json) {
    return Observable.create(function (observer) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(json),
            success: function (response) {
                observer.next([json.id, json]);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                observer.next([json.id]); // <== Notice this
            },
            complete: function () {
                observer.complete();
            }
        });
    });
}

var ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var ids$ = (id) => {
    return Observable.of(id);
};
var loadIds$ = (id) => {
    if(id == 4) return xhr('/echo/jsoneee/', {id: id});
    return xhr('/echo/json/', {id: id});
};

Observable.from(ids)
    .concatMap(id => loadIds$(id))
    .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

This way you can avoid `forkJoin()` completely. Also be aware that `catch()` operator automatically unsubscribes from its source. This operator is intended to continue with another Observable so it's now very useful in cases such as yours.

You could of course use:

```
.catch((error, caught) => {
    return caught;
})
```

This however causes resubscription and thus reemission of all values from the beginning which is usually undesired.

There's also `onErrorResumeNext()` operator that simply ignores the errors but that's probably not what you want.

See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4f1zmeyd/1/

A slightly similar question: [get new ticket then retry first request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953419/get-new-ticket-then-retry-first-request/39955002#39955002)

Comment: I would rather not have to modify `xhr()` according to this example. But I am not sure why this is working though as I want it to with `catch`? https://jsfiddle.net/ibrahimislam/ecLp6h1u/

Comment: @lbrahim You won't get it working with `catch()` because it doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: But if you will see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/ibrahimislam/ecLp6h1u. It is working as expected.

Comment: @lbrahim No, it's not the same. This just ignores the error and continues without including the failed id in the response. You'll get exactly the same result by using just `onErrorResumeNext()` without `catch()` at all