# Is there a nice/succinct way to refactor out embedded loops and instead use an Rx operator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Take the following function

```
function test(callbackFn) {
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var k = 1; k < 100; k++) {
        callbackFn(i, k);
    }  
  }
}
```

The intention of function test is that it should call the callbackFn as follows

```
callbackFn(1, 1); callbackFn(1, 2)...callbackFn(1, 100);
callbackFn(2, 1); callbackFn(2, 2)...callbackFn(2, 100);
...
```

I would like to refactor out the **for** loops. Is there a suitable **RxJs** operator which would allow me to do this?

I have looked at the zip, concat and merge operators but they don't seem to suit the use case.

Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you like two foreach calls?

Comment: My real world problem is much more complicated than this. I wanted to keep the question as simple as possible.

Comment: `Also, I don't want to embed two array.forEach calls` there is no array there, so you can't even forEach it. Unless that code represents iterating over an array. Or two arrays? It's not exactly clear.

Comment: `My real world problem is much more complicated than this.` yet this is _too_ simplified. What is the exact intention here? We need a bit more details. Are you iterating over two arrays? Nested arrays? Is it one array with 10 elements? One array of 100 elements? unknown amount of arrays? What is the problem you want to solve exactly? Are you sure you need to start from 1 instead of 0? Do you simply want to call (pseudo-code) `callback([1-10], [1-1000])` where those represent ranges and you want all permutations? Is it always going to be those numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `concatMap()` should work for you depending on what the `callbackFn(i, k)` is supposed to do.

These two question are about calling series of requests in order, which might be very similar to what you need to do:

- [Angular 2 + rxjs - how return stream of objects fetched with several subsequent http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566268/angular-2-rxjs-how-return-stream-of-objects-fetched-with-several-subsequent/39578646#39578646)
- [How to use exhaustMap in ReactiveX/rxjs 5 in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713531/how-to-use-exhaustmap-in-reactivex-rxjs-5-in-typescript/39589408#39589408)

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was the cartesian product. This can be achieved easily enough by using the **concatMap** operator.

Here is the refactored function

```
function test(callbackFn) {
    Rx.Observable.range(1, 10)
      .concatMap(i => Rx.Observable.range(1, 100), (i, k) => [i, k])
      .subscribe(([i, k]) => callbackFn(i, k));
}
```

Hopefully this example can be of use to someone.