# RxJS + (async/await) for (multiple-event) use cases

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, rxjs, bluebird

I am writing a Javascript App to get data from sensors. I started using **ES6 Promises + Generators** using **Bluebird** and the **Bluebird.cororutine** in both (client and server), but it didn't work fine.

I was advised that Promises didn't work properly in *(multiple-event) use cases*, and that an alternative could be **RxJS**.

I've taken a look to RxJS, and it looks like can do the same as the Promises but even better.
I wanted to use generators (**async/await**) to write the async code to look as sync, and my question is:

Can I use **RxJS + (async/await)** or RxJS has already its own way to do the same as (async/await) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Async/await is not part of ES6, it's scheduled for ES7. So you're probably not going to use it any time soon in JavaScript. [TypeScript supports async/await for ES5 since 2.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#21).

It think you'll be able to use RxJS with async/await when it comes out. Async/await works with Promises, just like RxJS even though it mostly works with Observables. There are methods such as `Observable.toPromise()` to convert an Observables to Promises and most Observables also accept a Promise as a parameter.

So I think both are going to be well interchangable (I haven't tried thi personally).

If your primary interest is to make you code more readable than RxJS is a good choice to reduce callback hell.

These two examples show how to call multiple HTTP requests in order using [`Observable.concatMap()` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap). Both examples are written in TypeScript but it should be basically the same in 
ES6 as well. Also these examples use the new RxJS implementation (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS):

- [Angular 2 + rxjs - how return stream of objects fetched with several subsequent http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566268/angular-2-rxjs-how-return-stream-of-objects-fetched-with-several-subsequent/39578646#39578646)
- [How to use exhaustMap in ReactiveX/rxjs 5 in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713531/how-to-use-exhaustmap-in-reactivex-rxjs-5-in-typescript/39589408#39589408)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. :).  Referent to asyn / await you can use it with babel and bluebird has the coroutine method that does the same.

Comment: @ToniBenitez Interesting, I didn't know that :) https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/