# Choosing the right RxJS construct in order to ensure one subscription completes before another one

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5, ngrx

I am facing a **RxJS** issue.

My app is currently designed as follows: I have two different clients: `ClientA` & `ClientB` that subscribe to two different Observables: `ObservableA` & `ObservableB`.

Note that the app also mutates a variable called `aVariable`.

Here is the flow:

1. `ClientA` subscribes to `ObservableA`.
2. `ClientB` subscribes to `ObservableB`.
3. `ObservableB` subscription read `false` from `aVariable` and completes.
4. `ObservableA` subscription sets `aVariable` to `true` and completes (later than `ObservableB`).

Whereas what is really intended was for `ObservableA`'s subscription to complete before `ObservableB`'s so that `ClientB` would read `true` from `aVariable`... Or to put it another way, somehow ensure that `ObservableB`'s subscription waits till the other subscription has completed.

I am not sure what RxJS construct to use in order to achieve what I want (I currently use plain Observables). I believe I need more than plain Observables here...

Can someone please help?

P.S. *Note that `aVariable` is held in a **ngrx store** but I don't think that is relevant to this issue...*

P.P.S. *The above is a simplification of my real app.*

Comment: Usually when you want to run asynchronous tasks in order you'd use `concat` or `concatMap`. See maybe similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566268/angular-2-rxjs-how-return-stream-of-objects-fetched-with-several-subsequent/39578646#39578646 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713531/how-to-use-exhaustmap-in-reactivex-rxjs-5-in-typescript/39589408#39589408

Comment: Hi Martin. The only trouble is that those are different clients. Is is not possible to use concat therefore.

Comment: Can you give a code sample of what you mean of how fits together?  I'm not clear on: What is `Client A`? What do you mean you complete the subscription? What you mean by a "plain" `Observable`.

Comment: I meant `ClientA` is located in another class that `ClientB`. By plain Observable I meant an Observable as opposed to all to the other constructs/classes that extend Observable such as ConnectedObservable etc. (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/).

Comment: By completing I mean: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscriber.js~Subscriber.html#instance-method-complete

Comment: @paulpdaniels: Does that answer your questions? Can I provide any other information?

Comment: @balteo does my proposed answer work for you?

Comment: @MarkvanStraten Thanks. Yes it does indeed. Sorry I had missed your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem with a intermediate Subject in which you emit a value when streamB gets subscribed to:

```js
const completeStreamA = new Rx.Subject();

const streamA = Rx.Observable.never()
  .takeUntil(completeStreamA);

const streamB = Rx.Observable.of('aValueOnStreamB')
  .do(() => completeStreamA.next('complete stream A'));

//clientA subscribes immediately
streamA.subscribe(
  next => console.log('a->next->'+next),
  err => console.log('a->error->' + err.message),
  () => console.log('a->complete')
);

setTimeout(() => {
  //simulate later subscription by clientB
  streamB.subscribe(
    next => console.log('b->next->'+next),
    err => console.log('b->error->' + err.message),
    () => console.log('b->complete')
  );
}, 3 * 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.3/Rx.js"></script>
```

Only after the streamB gets subscribed to it will next a value into the `completeStreamA` subject which will complete streamA. The output of above code:

```
a->complete
b->next->aValueOnStreamB
b->complete
```